# Getting the minimum value for multiple string values R

Tags: r, string

I'm working with a juvenile crime database and need to report the onset offending age.  I currently have the names and age at offending, many of the subjects are repeat offenders and I need to isolate the earliest age of offending.  I could go through line by line (31,000+ lines) but I am hoping there is any easier way to accomplish this.

What I have

```
Subject A      15
Subject A      17
Subject A      17
Subject B      11
Subject B      12
Subject B      15
Subject B      17
```

What I need

```
Subject A      15 
Subject A      15
Subject A      15
Subject B      11
Subject B      11
Subject B      11
Subject B      11
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few ways to do that:

```
# your sample data
df <- read.table(header=F, text="
Subject_A      15
Subject_A      17
Subject_A      17
Subject_B      11
Subject_B      12
Subject_B      15
Subject_B      17", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(df) <- c("Subject", "Age") # add some column names
```

Using base R `ave`:

```
df$Min_Age <- ave(df$Age, df$Subject, FUN = min)
```

Or using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(Min_Age = min(Age))
```

Or using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Min_Age := min(Age), by = Subject]
```

If you just want to replace the `Age` column with minimum values instead of creating a new column, you can replace the `Min_Age` entries in each solution with the existing column name `Age`.

Edit: here's a little benchmark (excluding the for loop since I don't think that's how it should be done).

```
df <- data.frame(Subject = sample(LETTERS, 1e4, TRUE), 
                 Age = sample(10:99, 1e4, TRUE))

dt <- as.data.table(df)

library(microbenchmark)
library(doBy)

microbenchmark(
  ave1 = {ave(df$Age, df$Subject, FUN = min)},
  ave2 = {with(df, ave(Age, Subject, FUN = min))},
  dplyr1 = {df %>% group_by(Subject) %>% mutate(Min_Age = min(Age))},
  dplyr2 = {df%>% group_by(Subject) %>% arrange(Subject,Age) %>% mutate(Min_Age=Age[1])},
  data.table = {dt[, Min_Age := min(Age), by = Subject]},
  doBy = {summaryBy(Age ~ Subject, df, FUN = min, full.dimension = TRUE)},
  lapply = {with(df, unsplit(lapply(split(Age, Subject), min), df[[1]]))},
  unit = "relative", 
  times = 100)

# Unit: relative
#      expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
#ave1        1.022080  1.015667  1.029203  1.040314  3.017348   100
#ave2        1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100
#dplyr1      1.158047  1.168557  1.207314  1.229463  1.075171   100
#dplyr2      4.452059  4.408963  4.424622  4.374746  3.692858   100
#data.table  1.143520  1.212317  1.265719  1.280680  3.265307   100
#doBy       18.047627 17.584799 17.609035 17.470075 19.118029   100
#lapply      1.164438  1.120205  1.117074  1.116633  3.186735   100
```

So base R's `ave` performs quite well in this scenario, although results might change depending on group sizes in your actual data.

Update: included `doBy` and `lapply` version in benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `summaryBy` from the `doBy` package.

```
> library(doBY)
> summaryBy(V2~V1, data = dat, FUN = min, full.dimension = TRUE)
```

Or another way with `split` and `unsplit`

```
> s <- with(dat, split(V2, V1))
> dat$V2 <- unsplit(lapply(s, min), dat$V1)
```

And one more with `ddply`

```
> library(plyr)
> ddply(dat, .(V1), summarize, min = rep(min(V2), length(V2)))
```

where `dat` is

```
dat <- read.table(text = "SubjectA      15
SubjectA      17
SubjectA      17
SubjectB      11
SubjectB      12
SubjectB      15
SubjectB      17")
```

And since we're going benchmarking everything, base R is the fastest out of my three.

```
> f <- function(){
      dat$V2 <- with(dat, unsplit(lapply(split(V2, V1), min), dat[[1]]) )
      dat
  }
> microbenchmark(f())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
#    f() 108.788 110.4575 111.0665 112.108 251.813   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your data in a dataframe with 2 columns or are these separate strings?

If it is a dataframe with 2 columns (let's say the column names are "name" and "age") and the variable name for the dataframe is "crime":

```
split.crime <- split(crime, name)
result.df <- data.frame()
for (sub.df in split.crime) {
   min.age <- min(df$age)
   new.sub.df <- data.frame(name = sub.df$name, age = min.age)
   result.df <- rbind(result.df, new.sub.df) }
rm(split.crime)
result.df
```

This is a VERY transparent and slow version. I'm sure it can be done with less code and faster. For your size of dataframe, it should work just fine.